# Is there a way to set the API route path at top of file name in NextJS 13?

Tags: javascript, next.js

So I am using Next JS 13 `route.ts` file to create API routes. I know that it follows file based naming convention but I was curious to know if a decorator or something can also be used to overwrite that?

Like let's say:

```
import { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

const GET = (req: NextRequest) => {
    return new Response('Hello NEXT JS');
};
export { GET };
```

I am having a common `API_ROUTES` constant which handles all sorts of paths:

```
const END_POINTS = {
    CREATE_USER: '/register',
};
```

Now I use this:
`import {END_POINTS} from "@/constants";`

And I want to import this in backend too to ensure that both of these remain in sync. I cannot dynamically update these file names and I am worried if my APIs grow then I have to create sub folders which may end up breaking everything.

What I am looking for is something like:

```
import { NextRequest } from 'next/server';
import {END_POINTS} from '@/constants';

@RouterTo("/api/get-user") // @RouteTo(END_POINTS.GET_USER)
const GET = (req: NextRequest) => {
    return new Response('Hello NEXT JS');
};
export { GET };
```

I know this is like defeating the complete purpose of file based routing but just wanted to know if NEXT let's you do things this way or its just not possible at all?

Comment: just for curiosity, why would you need it? just hast the name of the file to `get-user`

Comment: Actually when revising the versions of API, I have to re-arrange these files to point it to right endpoints and then make the same changes to the constants, however with something like this it slightly helps me maintain the consistency at both places.